# yii app render contact page in view of another model

Tags: php, yii

I want to render contact page generated by yii app into the view of another model controller. view.php

i used require_once() as
       require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\protected\site/contact.php');

it render the contact page but when submit button is pressed nothing going to happen..

what is the problem??

Edit:- I solved it...

Comment: Downvote for duplicate posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742055/yii-render-a-contact-form-into-a-view-of-another-model-yii-app

Answer (score 2):

In a view, `$this` refers to the current controller. So you can simply run `$this->renderPartial('view')` to do that "the correct way"

If you need views from another controller, just use an "absolute" path:

`$this->renderPartial('/otherController/view')`

Comment: thanks for the help... will you please help me for this one-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747936/yii-app-how-to-make-hidden-field-for-date-current-date-in-create-view